# Sequilize.js - Association, 2 tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Technologies used: Node.js, Express.js, Sequilize.js

I'm trying to connect two tables. There is a `user` table and a `color` table.

A `color` belongs to a `user`, and a `user` can have **one** color.

My file structure:

```
My Project
|__config
   |__db.js
|__models
  |__user.js
  |__color.js
|__routes
  |__index.js
|__app.js
```

In my `user.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('user', {
        /* attributes, such as: username */
    });
};
```

In my `color.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('color', {
        color: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
};
```

Then in `db.js` this is where I configure these files:

```
const db = {};

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.user = sequelize.import('../models/user.js');
db.color = sequelize.import('../models/color.js');


db.color.belongsTo(db.user);
db.user.hasOne(db.color);

module.exports = db;
```

Now is where the trouble begins. When someone creates a new `user` account (using a POST request), they must also select a `color`. So the user information is going to go into the `user` table, and the color information will go into the `color` table... but how do I do this? How do I link these two tables at the create phase. Below is what I have so far.

My POST request is like this in my `index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/db');

router.post('/createNewUser', function(req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username
    const color = req.body.color

    db.user.create({
        username: username
        color: color
    }, {
       include: db.color
   }).then(function(result) {
        //do something
   }).catch(function(err) {
        //in case of error
   });
});
```

Creating the tables works fine (all that config code is in the `app.js` file, not included here). The tables get created; the username is put into the `user` table and the color is placed in the `color` table, but the `userID` in the `color` table is `null.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay problem solved. Where I create a new user and color, it should look like this:

```
router.post('/createNewUser', function(req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username
    const color = req.body.color

    db.color.create({
        color: color
        user: {
            username: username
        }
    }, {
       include: [db.color]
   }).then(function(result) {
        //do something
   }).catch(function(err) {
        //in case of error
   });
});
```

This will link the 2 tables together; it will automatically create a column in the `color` table called `userID`, which will be the same value as `id` in the `user` table.